# PHP login page errors out with 11 errors

Tags: php, mariadb, wamp

I try to use login PHP and I get 11 errors back

PHP Code

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';

// To prevent mysql injection
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

// Query the database for user

$sql = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Failed to query 
database'.mysqli_error($con));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ( $row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password ){
echo "login success! Welcome".$row['username'];
} else {
echo "Failed to login!";
```

When I go to login these are the errors I get ( the 1st error says unknow database login, but thats what my database is called

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database
>   'login'     in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 2    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0    2  0.0002  401664  mysqli_connect (
>   ) ...\process.php:2
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php     on line 7    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to
>   be     mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 7
>   Call Stack    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>   2 0.0031  402632  mysqli_real_escape_string ( )   ...\process.php:7
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php     on line 8    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to
>   be     mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 8
>   Call Stack    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>   2 0.0047  402744  mysqli_real_escape_string ( )   ...\process.php:8
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php     on line 13    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 13 
>   Call Stack    #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>   2 0.0062  402792  mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( )  ...\process.php:13
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php     on line 14    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   null     given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 14    Call
>   Stack    #    Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}(
>   ) ...\process.php:0    2  0.0079  402792  mysqli_query (
>   ) ...\process.php:14
>
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: con in
>   C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php     on line 14    Call Stack
>     Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}( )   ...\process.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   null     given in C:\wamp64\www\Login\process.php on line 14    Call
>   Stack    #    Time    Memory  Function    Location    1   0.0002  401664  {main}(
>   ) ...\process.php:0    2  0.0099  402792  mysqli_error (
>   ) ...\process.php:14    Failed to query database

DB
[image: DB]

DB NEW
[image: DB NEW]

Comment: I gave as much info was I could find

Comment: Did you create the database `login`?

Comment: Yes I did make the db

Comment: I added a pic of the db I made

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing and matching a ton of paradigms and have undefined variables as well.
If you're going to use prepared statements (which yes, you should), you need to use the methods necessary to query a database that way.

First, in your screenshot I see that MariaDB is running on port 3307, but you're not specifying so in your script. Seeing as MariaDB's default port is 3306, it is rightfully failing. Change it to something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "login");
if ( !$link )
    throw new Exception( "Failed to connect; error: ${mysqli_connect_error()}");
```

It also goes without saying that you shouldn't be using a root account with no password.

After that you should make sure that you're actually passing in the correct variables. So instead of **$con** you have **$link**.

Now, you don't need to escape the username and the password since that is already being done during the prepare/execute process. So get rid of the following two lines:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);
```

What you should instead be doing is, when creating users, you should be using `password_hash` to hash the password, and when logging in, use `password_verify` to compare the entered password and the hashed DB record.

Anyway, now you need to prepare the statement, bind the params, execute the statement and get the result:

```
// check if the query is valid and prepare it
$sql = "select username, password from users where username = ? and password = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $link, $sql );
if ( !$stmt )
    throw new Exception( 'Failed to prepare statement: ' . mysqli_error($link) );

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result( $stmt );
```

Lastly you fetch the data:

```
if ( !( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) )
    // tell the user that the input data is invalid
    die( 'Failed to login' );

// query was successful
echo "Login success! Welcome ".$row['username'];
```

As I said, in reality you would store hashed passwords in the database, query the database for some columns with only the username, e-mail or whatever in the WHERE clause, then compare the password from the database with the user provided password. Something akin to this:

```
$sql = "select username, password from users where username = ?";
...
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result( $stmt );

if ( !( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) )
    // username doesn't exist

if ( !password_verify( $password, $row['password'] ) )
    die( 'Failed to login' );

// query was successful
echo "Login success! Welcome ".$row['username'];
```

Final note: you should really switch to PDO as it's more modern, robust and has a cleaner syntax than this mysqli mess.

Comment: Hey I tried what you said and now I am not getting an errors other then Failed to login, I am using the un and pw that I set in Db

Comment: What is the code you're using? If you copy/pasted the part with the password verification without replacing the password in the database with a hashed version of it, of course it isn't gonna work.